# Complexity of this simple algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, code-analysis, code-complexity

I did a algorithm to resolve a problem, but I don't know its complexity.
The algorithm verifies if all of the vertex of a graph are "good". A "good" vertex is a vertex that can access all  others vertexes of a graph following a path that started himself.

```
public static boolean verify(Graph graph)
{
    for(int i=0; i < graph.getVertex().size(); i++)
    {
        // List of vertexes visited 
        ArrayList<Character> accessibleVertex = new ArrayList<Character>();
        getChildren(graph.getVertex().get(i), graph.getVertex().get(i).getName(), accessibleVertex);    

        // If the count of vertex without father equals a count of the list of vertexes visited, his is a "good" vertex
        if((graph.getVertex().size()-1) == accessibleVertex.size())
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static void getChildren(Vertex vertex, char fatherName, ArrayList<Character> accessibleVertex)
{
    // Ignore the 'father'
    if(vertex.getName() != fatherName)
        addIfUnique(vertex.getName(), accessibleVertex);

    for(int i=0; i < vertex.getEdges().size(); i++)
    {
        getChildren(vertex.getEdges().get(i).otherVertex(), fatherName, accessibleVertex);
    }
}

private static void addIfUnique(char name, ArrayList<Character> accessibleVertex)
{
    boolean uniqueVertex = true;

    for(int i=0; i < accessibleVertex.size(); i++)
    {
        if(accessibleVertex.get(i).equals(name))
            uniqueVertex = false;
    }

    if(uniqueVertex)
        accessibleVertex.add(name);
}
```

[Graph tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSXt.png)

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: My first impression: O(n^3)

Comment: A method named `addIfUnique` taking an `ArrayList<Character>` suggests that you should be using a `Set<Character>` instead, and just calling `add`.

Comment: I think that this code will potentially loop infinitely if cycles exist in your graph.

Comment: Yes, the code can stay in loop infinitely, but on example, I have vertexes without edges, so it's a condition to stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the complexity is O(n^2), because you use a nested loop by calling:

```
getChildren(graph.getVertex().get(i), graph.getVertex().get(i).getName(), accessibleVertex);
```

Comment: So, the for loop in `verify` calling `getChildren()`, which contains a for loop - that's not a nested loop?

Comment: So do you think the asymptotic complexity would be O(n^2)?

Comment: No, I'm not making any claims as to the correct complexity; I'm merely questioning "because you didn't use a nested loop".

Comment: So, the complexity of all code is O(n^2)? The method addIfUnique not influence the complexity?

Comment: The method addIfUnique has a for loop, but doesnt influnce because if we add the for loop to the nested, which would be O(n) + (n^2), the result would be O(2n^2), that is, asymptotically, O(n^2).

Comment: Thank Simone and everyone, unfortunately I don't have reputation to thank you

Comment: I forgot to ask, O(n^2) is the same of O(v^2), where v is the count of vertex of graph?